# Create() or Render() for creating instances

Tags: java, libgdx, jbox2d

I am learning Java, LibGDX, Box2D via the use of projects and tutorials, I am following a tutorial at the moment and I wanted to raise a question regarding the render() loop and the create() method.

So first create() always gets called first, then render(). If I am creating a bunch of instances such as:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

    World world;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    BodyDef bodyDef;
    CircleShape circle;
    FixtureDef fixtureDef;
```

Should I use the `new` constructor here? or should I do that in the create() method?

```
@Override
public void create() {

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(800 / 2, 480 /2);
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(100, 300);
    circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(6f);
    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
```

Or should I place it in the render() method?

I am a bit unsure which is best, doing it in render seems a bit naff, would that not cause the game to constantly create new instances every loop iteration resulting in performance issues?

Oh and meant to ask, when I am defining properties of an object, such as circle.setRadius(), create method would be the right place?

Comment: Don't use `new` while declaring attributes, because some classes, like `SpriteBatch` if I remember well, need LibGDX's core classes to be initialized, especially the `Gdx.graphics` field, before being instanciated or an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definetely *not* use a lot of `new` in your `render` loop. On desktop this isn't really a big problem, but on handheld devices this will invoke the garbage collector too often, which will result in a laggy gameplay.

Whether you do it in the attribute declaration, or in `create` doesn't make a big difference. Both is done just once in your application's lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at some code snippets and this person was creating them in a method, at the end of the method circle.dispose(); gets called, will this stop the garbage collector from going bonkers if you do it like this?

Comment: @Gibbo No, calling `dispose()` will not prevent the garbage collector. It might even *invoke* it indirectly, because some objects might get set to `null`. When exactly the garbage collector kicks in is not really predictable. In general you should just try to avoid `new` and instead use `Pool`s whenever possible.

Comment: OK thanks, I am still learning so my code is going to be inefficient/crap anyway, will need to learn how to use libGDX's pool class.